# <a> not displaying in block format

Tags: html, css, web

I have a navbar with three `<a>` tags that form the buttons to link to different pages. I am currently working on mobilization for the site, and for some reason I cant make the dropdown display the buttons in block format.

My code:

```
 <span class="nav navbar-nav inline">
      <a href="#page-top" class="navbuttons"></a>
      <a href="contact" class="navbuttons">Contact</a>
      <a href="aboutus" class="navbuttons">About Us</a>
      <a href="projects" class="navbuttons">Projects</a>
 </span>

 .navbuttons {
      font-size: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  clear: left;
  margin-right: 24px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
 }

 @media (max-width: 768px) {
      a.navbuttons {
           display: block;
      }
 }
```

[image: And Here's a Screenshot]

Comment: I wonder why you've wrapping `<a>` tags inside a `<span>`. The shared code is not enough to exactly reproduce the result given in image... hope the answer helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `float` as well to get the expected behaviour of `block` element (*Assuming you need them to stack vertically in mobile devices*)

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  a.navbuttons {
       display: block;
       float:none;
  }
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Zakm/)